# Match filename in <link href="/path/?????/?????/????.css"

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Need to get the css file name from a link tag that is in a specific folder.

```
<link href="/assets/49f0ugdf8g/sub/style.css"   -> style.css
```

Currently have

```
match(`<link .*?href="\/assets\/(.*?\.css)"/i)
```

Which returns the path minus "/assets/".
Can it be extended to remove the rest of the path and just return the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be simpler not to use regex and to use the native JS [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function:

```
var link = document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0]; // or whatever JS to get your link element
var filename = link.href.split('/').pop(); // split the string by the / character and get the last part
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
match(<link .*?href="\/assets\/([^/]+\.css)"/i)
//                              ^^^^^ change here
```

I dropped the `?` because you probably want the capture group to be greedy. Also used `+` rather than `*` on the assumption there will always be at least one character in the "file" name.

Answer (score 0):

First, [be warned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Try this: `"\/assets\/(?:[^\/">]+\/)*([^\/">]*?.css)"`.

The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
match(`<link .*?href="\/assets\/(?:[^\/]*\/)*(.*?\.css)"/i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var link = '<link href="/assets/49f0ugdf8g/sub/style.css">';
var match = link.match(/<link .*?href="(.*)">/i);
var filename = match[1].split('/').pop();
```